# Exclude fields from a pydantic class

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a class like this,

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    
    field_1: str = Field(description='Field 1')
    field_2: dict = Field(description='Field 2')
    field_3: list = Field(description='Field 3')
```

I want to create child class inherting MyClass like this,

```
class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    
    field_4: str = Field(description='Field 4')
```

While creating the child class I need to disable field_2 being inherited (alternatively field_2 should be removed from MyChildClass after inheriting).

What can I achieve? What are the best practices surrounding this?

Comment: Depending on how complex your class is it might be simpler to just use composition instead of inheritance

Comment: in normal python letting a child class not inherit a specific method isn't possible right?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in PydanticV1: see discussion [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/2686).

I don't know for sure, but it should be possible in PydanticV2 (https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6699)

---

Speaking about best practices, what I would do is the following

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClassBase(BaseModel):
    field_1: str = Field(description='Field 1')
    field_3: list = Field(description='Field 3')

class MyClass1(MyClassBase):
    field_2: dict = Field(description='Field 2')

class MyClass2(MyClassBase):
    field_4: str = Field(description='Field 4')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pydantic you can easily achieve this with the exclude parameter

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClass(BaseModel):
    field_1: str = Field(description='Field 1')
    field_2: dict = Field(description='Field 2')
    field_3: list = Field(description='Field 3')

class MyChildClass(MyClass, exclude={'field_2'}):
    field_4: str = Field(description='Field 4')
```

Or when whipping up an instance, you can pinpoint the fields you' d rather not inherit by deploying the exclude parameter..

```
child_instance = MyChildClass(field_1='value1', field_3=['value3'], field_4='value4', exclude={'field_2'})
```